# Busy-waiting alternative

Tags: javascript, recursion, callstack, busy-waiting

I have a problem with a javascript-Function, where I can't use callback-Functions.

The function gets a List of "commands", and iterates over them. It performs one command after another.
In order to do that, I have to use a recursive Function with callbacks.

**Here's an example to describe it:**

```
function processList( inputArray, cb ){
    if(inputArray.length == 0) return cb();  //No commands left

    var command = inputArray.pop();          //Get last Element from the List
    processCommand(command, function(){      //Execute the command
        return processList(inputArray, cb);  //Continue with the next command, when this one finished
    });
}

function processCommand(command, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Processed command "+command);
        cb();
    }, 10);
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
processList( ["cmd1", "cmd2", "cmd3"], function(){
    console.log("DONE");
});
```

It works perfectly, one command is executed after the previous one.

**My Problem:**

The list contains thousands of Elements, and it's even possible that the list gets new commands during processing. And I reach the maximum call-stack within seconds.

I don't need the call-stack. When I finished the last command, there are just thousands of returns, which guide me back to the function, which started everything.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, and I don't want to use busy waiting (which makes the code extremly inefficient).

Is there another trick? Like signals or trashing the call-stack?

**Edit:**

Here's a jsFiddle for demonstration:  http://jsfiddle.net/db6J8/
*(Notice, that your browser-tab might freeze/crash)*

The error-Message is `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I tested it with Chrome, you might have to increase the Array in other Browsers (IE has a huge Callstack).

**Edit2:**

Thanks for you help, I didn't recognise the difference between adding/removing the timeout. Hover, it doesn't solve my Problem.
Here are some more details:
I have different commands. Some commands are synchronous, others are asynchronous. So I have to use callback-Functions, but still have the problem with the callstack.

Here's an updated example:

```
var commands = [];
for(var i=15000; i>=0;i--){ commands.push(i); }
    processList(commands, function(){
    alert("DONE");
});


function processList( inputArray, cb ){
    if(inputArray.length == 0) return cb();  //No commands left

    var command = inputArray.pop();          //Get last Element from the List



    processCommand(command, function(){      //Execute the command
        return processList(inputArray, cb);  //Continue with the next command, when this one finished
    });
}

function processCommand(command, cb){
    if(command%2 == 0){     //This command is synchron
        console.log("Processed sync. command "+command);
        cb();
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Processed async. command "+command);
            cb();
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B7APC/

Comment: I can run `processList` with 10,000 elements without facing any problems.

Comment: async comes to mind, async.queue https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

Comment: I can't detect a serious problem. Can you please show us the stack trace of the stackoverflow error, to identify which functions cause the problem? Are you sure that `processCommand` is always asynchronous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // setTimeout(function(){
>     console.log("Processed command " + command);
>     cb();
> // }, 1);
> ```

That's the reason. Without `setTimeout`, you easily will hit the call stack limit ([Demo with named functions](http://jsfiddle.net/db6J8/2/)):

```
Maximum recursion depth exceeded:
finishedCommand _display/:16
processCommand _display/:23
processList _display/:15
finishedCommand _display/:16
processCommand _display/:23
…
processList _display/:15
finishedCommand _display/:16
processCommand _display/:23
processList _display/:15
<Global Scope> _display/:16
```

Choose a synchronous loop instead of recursively calling `processCommand`.

If you put the `setTimeout` back into effect, each timer event will call the function with a fresh new call stack, and it will never overflow:

```
setTimeout(function later(){
    console.log("Processed command " + command);
    cb();
}, 1);
```

You see that the stack always looks like this when "DONE" is logged - regardless of how many commands you processed ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/db6J8/5/)):

```
BreakPoint at console.log()
readyHandler show/:8
processList show/:13
finishedCommand show/:17
later show/:24
<Global Scope> // setTimeout
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't recognise that. However I can't use that solution, because I have a combination of synchronous and asynchronous commands (see my updated question). If you can provide a working example, I'll except your answer :)

Comment: Having every second command synchronous still should work - the reached stack size will double but still be constant. If it's rather unpredictable, you can make *every* processing asynchronous by putting `setTimeout(cb, 1)` instead of `cb()` in the sync part, or you can "chunk" a few sync commands together which run in a loop and then call the (async) callback.

Comment: Thanks. In the worst case, I'll only have synchronous functions (in which case I reach the stack-limit), but using a combination of loops and callbacks should actually work.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe something like this wouldn't hold onto a call stack because it doesn't give the callback as a parameter.

```
function processList( inputArray, cb ){

    var processCommand = function(){
        if(inputArray.length == 0) cb();  //No commands left

        var command = inputArray.pop();
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Processed command "+command);
            processCommand();
        }, 10);
    };

    processCommand();
}
```

Comment: @Bergi It will call processCommand() once and from then on processCommand() will be called from the timeout function when the processing is done, therefore it will wait.

Comment: Uh, I see, you've merged the `processCommand` directly into the `processList`. I don't think that is what the OP wants.

Comment: You maybe right, but I think it might help the OP. Let's let him decide :)

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5WC6a/
But unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't solve the problem. I still reach the max. callstack-size, because the browser remembers the return-adresses.

Comment: @Bergi: It doesn't matter how ugly the solution is, as long as it performs one command after another, and isn't limited with the callstack.

Comment: Wow, that is ... strange. Can you explain me, why this code works? Whats the difference, if you pass the callback-Function?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect case for [promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec). tbh I haven't tried them out yet, but they're at the top of my list.
Have a loook at [sequencing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). Also, it is irrelevant whether the operations in a promise are sync or not.

So you'd have something like

```
commands.forEach(function(cmd) {
    execCmd(cmd).then(onSuccess, onFailure);
});
```

Sorry that's not very specific, but you'd have to do some more research.